# Puppeteer: content of frame cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

My test html:

```
<div id="mainBlock">
    <div  class="underBlock">
        Hello!
    </div>
</div>
```

i try to get content of div with class `underBlock` like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let response =  await page.goto('http://localhost/TestPup/Index.html');
    let block = await page.waitForXPath("//div[contains(@class,'underBlock')]")
    let frame = await block.contentFrame()
    console.log(frame.content())
    await browser.close();
})();
```

but i got error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null
```

Comment: Note that if the iframe is not in the same origin then you will get `Cross-Domain-Security-Error`. Unless you have control over the iframe as well, it might be impossible to get the content or access the iframe. If you have control over both the scraper and iframe then you might be interested in this: https://blog.kiprosh.com/accessing-cross-domain-iframe-contents/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, [`elementHandle.contentFrame()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#elementhandlecontentframe) only returns a frame for `iframe` elements, and you have a regular `div` that is contained in the main frame, that is, in the `page`, and inside which there are no frames.